# If $C|a$ and $C|b$ then $C|(ax+by)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $c|a$ and $c|b$ then $c|(ax+by)$ where $c,a,b$ are integers

Proof:

Suppose $c|a$ and $c|b$ then we can represent as the following:

$a=cx$ where $x$ is an integer

$b=cy$ where $y$ is an integer

Then adding both:

$a+b=cx+cy=c(x+y)$

therefore $c|a+b$

but how can i show $c|(ax+by)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Don't use $x$ and $y$ for different things. They are given in the statement of the problem, so you should choose other factors for $a$ and $b$.

Instead, write something like $a=cr,b=cs$. Then you get $$ax+by=crx+csy$$
and you should be able to complete it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $c$ divides both $a$ and $b$. Then $a = nc$ and $b = mc$ for some integers $n, m$. Then, assuming $x$ and $y$ are integers,
$$
ax + by = (nc)x + (mc)y = c(nx + my)
$$
Hence, $c$ divides $ax + by$.